# Information that used in console application in c# how can i write same info in message box

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

Good  days everyone.My problem is simple to knowing people but i don't know. Problem is this in code

```
object value = vr.ReadTypedValue();
Console.WriteLine("{0}({1},{2}):{3}", vr.NodeType, vr.Name, value.GetType().Name, value);
```

I want to write vr.NodeType,vr.Name,value.GetType().Name informations to MessageBox.Show in it.How can I do or how can i modify this code to solve my problem

Comment: is it winforms or console app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your message

```
string message = String.Format("{0}({1},{2}):{3}", 
                              vr.NodeType, vr.Name, value.GetType().Name, value);
```

And show it in `MessageBox`:

```
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

In console app:

add the

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll //Ty Alex
```

to your project and add the winforms code.

in winforms =

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}({1},{2}):{3}", 
               vr.NodeType, 
               vr.Name, 
               value.GetType().Name, 
               value));
```

messagebox code

```
MessageBox.Show("this shows a messagebox");
```

format code

```
string.Format("This line formats a {0} with the given {1}","string", "params");
```

Comment: It's a console application. So you need to import System.Windows.Forms

Comment: @Alex if `MessageBox` is available then I think it's not console

Comment: @Alex, question stated winforms and console app so i thought Husonos was reverting a console app to a winforms app

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy No. A console application is free to create windows. (A console exe on process start is allocated a console – if one isn't inherited from the parent process – there is no other difference. A windows exe can programmatically allocate a console via the Win32 API `AllocConsole` and then use console APIs.)

Comment: @Richard I didn't say it's not possible to create windows in console application. I said that if MessageBox is available then it's possibly not console application (or at least System.Windows.Forms already referenced)

Answer (score 0):

```
object value = vr.ReadTypedValue();
string message = string.Format("{0}({1},{2}):{3}", vr.NodeType, vr.Name, value.GetType().Name, value);
System.Windows.Form.MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Comment: First of all no not converting console app to winform. I working on validation so i am examining examples but all of them uses console to make contact with the user.Thanks to all of you that answer my problem...